# How to write to file with same name as HTML form field

Tags: php, html, forms

I have made an attempt to write a PHP code that takes the contents of an HTML form then write them into a file.  I have that down just fine, but I have another problem. I want to take an input of a field in the form and make it the file name that I am writing to.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['forwhom']) && isset($_POST['importance']) && isset($_POST['message'])) {
$file = "students.html";
$data = nl2br('-' . $_POST['forwhom'] . ':' . ' ' . $_POST['message']  . ' ' . $_POST['importance'] . "\n");
$ret = file_put_contents($file, $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
if($ret === false) {
    die('There was an error writing this file');
}
else {
    echo "Success!  Student added to database.";
}
}
else {
   die('no post data to process');
}

?>
```

Currently, I am writing to the file "students.html"  However, I want to write to the file "Dad.html", which happens to be the input in the field by the name of *forwhom*.

Basically, I am asking this:  What do I use to replace "students.html" (line 3) so that the file name will be the same as the input of the field *forwhom*?

I apologize if that didn't make any sense.  Thank you very much!

Comment: `$file = $_POST['forwhom'] . 'html' ` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First check if data has been posted on your form using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"`.
2. For simplicity sake save all your `"POST"` requests in a variable eg.

   $file = $_POST['forwhom'];
   $importance = $_POST['importance'];
   $message = $_POST['message'];
3. I sometimes find it much easier using `empty()` instead of `isset()`.
4. Create a variable, lets say `$status` which would store all your messages, then any where in your HTML section you just use the `$status` to display the appropriate message to the user. Check below how i make use of `$status` in the form. 
   By doing so is much cleaner and makes your code more dynamic in a sense.

   ```
            <?php

               if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

                   $file = $_POST['forwhom'];  
                   $importance = $_POST['importance'];
                   $message = $_POST['message'];

                   if (!empty($file) && !empty($importance) && !empty($message)) {

                       $data = nl2br('-' . $file . ':' . ' ' . $message  . ' ' . $importance . "\n");      
                       $file .= ".html";       
                       $ret = file_put_contents($file, $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

                       if ($ret == true) {
                           $status = "Success!  Student added to database.";
                       } else {
                           $status = "Error writing to file!";
                       }
                   } else {
                       $status = "Please enter name, email and message";
                   }

               }
               ?>
       <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
       <head>
           <title></title>
       </head>
       <body>
       <form action="" method="post">
           <ul>
               <li>
                   <label for="name">Name: </label>
                   <input type="text" name="forwhom" id="forwhom">
               </li>
               <li>
                   <label for="email">Email: </label> 
                   <input type="text" name="importance" id="importance"> 
               </li>
               <li>
                   <label for="message">Your Message: </label><br>
                   <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>
               </li>
               <li>
                   <input type="submit" value="Go!">
               </li>
           </ul>
       <?php if(isset($status)): ?>
       <p><?= $status; ?></p>
       <?php endif; ?>
       </form>
       </body>
       </html>
   ```

   I added a form just for explanation sake, hope it helps.

Comment: Perfect!  That does exactly what I want, and the code is a bit easier to deal with as well.  Thank you very, very much!